# Undefened reference when trying to inherit signal on Windows (works on Linux)

Tags: c++, qt

I'm making shared library, where i have base abstract class  Generator with signals and derived class G3000. And main project where i connect signals from G3000 to mainwindow. On linux everything works fine, but when i tried to compile on Windows i'v got undefined reference to the signal of base class Generator. Can't figure it why does this happens. 
If i'm trying to connect this signal to some slot within shared library it everything works again.

Base class

```
#ifndef GENERATOR_H
#define GENERATOR_H

#include <QObject>
#include <generators_global.h>

class Generator : public QObject
{
  Q_OBJECT
public:
    explicit Generator(int i_vid, int i_pid, float i_lowestFreq, float i_highestFreq, float i_tSweepMin, float i_tSweepMax, QObject * parent = 0);

signals:
    void disconnected();

};
#endif // GENERATOR_H
```

constructor

```
Generator::Generator(int a, int b, float c, float d, float e, float f, QObject *parent) : QObject(parent)
{ }
```

and derived class

```
#ifndef G3000_H
#define G3000_H

#include <generator.h>
class GENERATORS_EXPORT G3000 : public Generator
{
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    explicit G3000(QObject * parent = 0);
    ~G3000();
};

#endif // G3000_H
```

constructor

```
G3000::G3000(QObject *parent) :
    Generator(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, parent)
{ }
```

and when calling from MainWindow

```
#ifndef MAINWINDOW_H
#define MAINWINDOW_H

#include <G3000/g3000.h>


namespace Ui {
class MainWindow;
}

class MainWindow : public QMainWindow
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    explicit MainWindow(QWidget *parent = 0);
    ~MainWindow()
public slots:
    void generator_disconnected();

private:

    G3000 generator;
};

#endif // MAINWINDOW_H



    MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent) :
    QMainWindow(parent),
    ui(new Ui::MainWindow)
{

    connect(&generator, &G3000::disconnected, this, &MainWindow::generator_disconnected);
}
```

i'm getting

```
undefined reference to `Generator::disconnected()'
```

but any other methods can be called. And if i'll redeclare signal in derived class it will work too.

Comment: try  this form :  connect(&generator, Signal(disconnected()), this,  SLOT(generator_disconnected())); instead

Comment: @basslo SIGNAL, not Signal

Comment: show us the constructor G3000. Seems its calls default Generator's constructor. Maybe it wasn't generated by moc because of that

Comment: @Michael O : thanks! Didn't notice.

Comment: @Zhu also, your current form would work (I guess) if you added brackets: `G3000::disconnected()`

Comment: @AmirRasulov added constructors

Comment: @Zhu Now, from this point I have no idea how it could be(